# How do I remove lines of text before this character?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

Let's say I have this little text file, for example reasons.

```
thisisanexample@gmail.com:948
1234@aol.com:11111===
xxxepicalwizardsomethingidontknowxxx@yahoo.co.uk:123
```

How would I remove all the text before `===`?

I use Windows 10 so no need for anything about Linux.

Comment: Select them and press either Backspace or Delete.

Comment: _A general FYI that's off-topic, but wanted to share from my own experience: You may want to look at [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) in lieu of Notepad++ for a variety of reasons, but mainly due to Notepad++ having almost non-existent community development, lack of themes and true dark theme support, a myriad of untrusted plugins, etc._

Comment: VS Code is arguably overkill for general text editing, especially since it can be extremely resource intensive for what should be simple, low-cost operations like text replacement/removal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*(?====)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  .*        # 0 or more any character but newline
  (?=       # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    ===     # 3 equal sign
  )         # end lookahead
```

**Result for given example:**

```
thisisanexample@gmail.com:948
===
xxxepicalwizardsomethingidontknowxxx@yahoo.co.uk:123
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i also wanted it to be that it removes all of the text before it (including the previous lines eg. thisisanexample)

Comment: @Your question wasn't clear. Change Find what: `\A.*(?====)` and Check `. matches newline`. Ths will remove ALL lines from the beginning of the file until `===`  If this doesn't work as expected, please, edit your question and add sample lines and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Following sequence should do the thing you want

1. `CTRL+H` to open find and `Replace` window
2. Select `Search mode` as `Regular expression` and select `matches newline`
3. Enter the following regex in `Find what` field `^.*(?=(\===))` (replace the === with any character set you want)
4. Keep `Replace with` field empty
5. Keep the cursor before the first character on file and keep `Direction` as Down
6. Click the `Replace` button

Comment: i have a newer version of np++, how do i change the direction?

Comment: what is the version you are using?

Comment: 7.7.1, i'm not sure what to do

Comment: If it has backward direction checkbox, untick it

Comment: i unchecked backward direction, copy and pasted everything, left replace with empty, put in your code in the find what section, used regular expression and selected the space before the first character and nothing happened